# PHP два раза выполняет Redis и Memcached скрипты

Tags: php, redis, memcached

Простейший код:

```
<?php
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
$redis->incr("views");
```

Когда его запускаю через Php консоль(php -a), то все отлично.

Когда запускаю через http, то инкремент на 2 получаю. Наверное пхп несколько раз выполняет код? Помогите куда копать? Психанул и попробовал Memcached - получаю тоже самое.

конфиг nginx если нужно

```
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот вопрос задавался много раз, но лень искать.

*ЧПУ на сайте надо реализовывать с умом*. Если РНР код служит обработчиком 404 ошибки, то перед тем как выполнять любые действия, **надо проверять валидность запроса**. И если запрос некорректный - например, к несуществующему файлу, то никаких действий выполнять не следует, а надо быстро завершить скрипт, вернув 404 статус.

Comment: я запускал напрямую скрипт, без ЧПУ. т.е. при запуске http://www.domain.com/test.php , вызовется все равно index.php ? (при моем конфиге nginx)

Comment: try_files - это ЧПУ.

Comment: да, действительно. не хватало favicon.ico файла и этот запрос шел опять на index.php. Буду искать как проверять на валидность.